# How to open a csv file and go through onto next line in a loop

Tags: python

I need to find profit/loss from two different lines on a csv file. I cant find a way to hold a variable whilst on one row and then once i move onto another line have the same variable to make a comparison.

I have already tried the next() function but have had no luck.

import csv

```
symbolCode = input("Please enter a symbol code: ")
with open("prices.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    with open(symbolCode + ".csv", "w") as d:
        writer = csv.writer(d)
        for row in reader:
            item = 0
            item2 = 0
            if symbolCode == row[1]:
                print(row)
                writer.writerow(row)

    d.close()
```

I expect to find an output of a number but while having used the two other numbers to minus and equal the output

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
symbolCode = input("Please enter a symbol code: ")
with open("prices.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    with open(symbolCode + ".csv", "w") as d:
        writer = csv.writer(d)
        previous_row = None   # <--- initialize with special (empty/none) value
        for row in reader:
            item = 0
            item2 = 0
            if symbolCode == row[1]:
                print(row)
                writer.writerow(row)
            if previous_row != None:      # <-- if we're not processing the very first row.
                if previous_row[7] < row[7]:   # <-- do your comparison with previous row
                    print("7th value is bigger now")  # <-- do something
            previous_row = row     # <-- store this row to be the previous row in the next loop iteration
```

Note that I've left out the `d.close()` line. It's not needed when you open a file in a `with` statement. Other than that, I only **added** lines to your example, and marked these line with `# <--` comments.